# Clarification on solution of Google Code Jam 2019, Round 1C, problem 1

Tags: algorithm

Consider problem ["Robot Programming Strategy" from the Google Code Jam 2019, Round 1C](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/00000000000516b9/0000000000134c90). The solution states at the end that

> We will eliminate at least one opponent with each move, so after A moves, we will either have our winning program or know that the case is IMPOSSIBLE.

However, it seems to me that this is wrong, because different moves do not necessarily eliminate different opponents.

Take for example the opponents "RR" and "PP" and consider the solution described in the analysis: our program would be "PP", but it is not true that after 2 moves our program eliminates all the opponents. The answer should be "IMPOSSIBLE".

My question is: do you agree that at the end we should also check that our program actually defeats every single opponent, and if not we should answer "IMPOSSIBLE"?

Comment: Take for example the opponents "RRR" and "PPP": our program would be "PPP" - why is that so?

Comment: Because "we should pick the move that ties one and beats the other", as described in the analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should exclude those are eliminated already. So for the example you give - "RR" and "PP", the sequence "PS" can beat both of them.

This greedy algorithm works this way:

```
Opponent 1 : RR
Opponent 2 : PP
Me         :
```

Choose "P" since it can tie or win for all.

```
Opponent 1 : RR
Opponent 2 : PP
Me         : P
```

The Opponent 1 is eliminated from the first move. Now there is only "P" left so I pick "S".

```
Opponent 2 : PP
Me         : PS
```

% Nit: Number of opponents must be `2^K-1`.